# A small question about $M/\partial M$, where $M$ is a manifold.

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about topology.

Suppose $M$ is a space with boundary $\partial M$, is that possible to obtain a space with the quotient topology $M/\partial M$? If this is possible, does $M/\partial M$ have a boundary?

I guess this quotient space $M/\partial M$ makes sense and it has no boundary, i.e. $\partial(M/\partial M)=0$. This works for $M$ being a disk $D$, whose boundary is a circle $S$.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Well, as *topological space*, of course we can form the quotient space $M/\partial M$. But the question is, whether it is still a manifold, i.e. in the new point (which arose in place of $\partial M$), does it have a neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball?

Comment: For a smooth (or PL) manifold we have a collar for the boundary, so it reduces to showing that $(\partial M \times [0,\epsilon))/\partial M \cong \text{ball}$.

Comment: Here is an example where $M/\partial M$ is not a manifold. Take $M=S^1\times [0,1]$. Quotienting by the boundary, you get something that is clearly not a manifold (the point $[\partial M]$ has no neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: @dc2814: Excellent point. Of course, I was thinking of the case $\partial M$ connected. xyzzyz's argument below makes the same assumption.

Comment: I make no such assumption. From the fact that $\partial M$ has to be homology sphere it follows that $\partial M$ has to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [When does the quotient of a manifold with boundary become a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271123/when-does-the-quotient-of-a-manifold-with-boundary-become-a-manifold) , but I don't find the answers there fully satisfactory.

As mentioned earlier in the comments, the boundary $\partial M$ of a smooth manifold $M$ has a collar neighbourhood $\partial M \subset U \simeq \delta M \times [0, 1)$. This gives us a neigbourhood of our singular point in $M/\partial M$, which I will denote by $x$ $(= [\partial M] \in M/\partial M$. So, in $M/\partial M$, we have a neighbourhood $x \in \tilde{U} =  (\partial M \times [0, 1))/\partial M$.

The local homology $H_\star(\tilde{U}, \tilde{U} - x)$ should be isomorphic to the homology of $S^n$ if $M/\partial M$ was a manifold. We have a long exact sequence of reduced homology:

$\ldots \to \tilde{H}_k(\tilde{U}) \to \tilde{H}_k(\tilde{U},\tilde{U}-x) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(\tilde{U}-x) \to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(\tilde{U}) \to \ldots$

It's easy to see that $\tilde{U}$ is contractible (as it's basically cone over $\partial M$), so by exactness we get isomorphisms $\tilde{H}_k(\tilde{U},\tilde{U}-x) \simeq \tilde{H}_{k-1}(\tilde{U}-x)$. As $\tilde{U}$ is a cone over $\partial M$ and $x$ is a cone point, $\tilde{U} - x$ deformation retracts onto $\partial M$, so $\tilde{H}_{*+1}(\tilde{U}, \tilde{U}-x) \simeq \tilde{H}_*(\tilde{U} - x) \simeq \tilde{H}_*(\partial M)$

As local homology of $x$ is supposed to be the same as homology of $S^n$ if $M/\partial M$ is has to be manifold, the necessary condition for $\partial M$ is that $\partial M$ is a homology sphere. I'm quite sure that it actually needs to be an actual sphere, though I don't see how to show this.